# Creating a fluid panel in GWT to fill the page?

Tags: java, gwt

I would like a panel in GWT to fill the page without actually having to set the size.  Is there a way to do this?  Currently I have the following:

```
public class Main  implements EntryPoint
{
    public void onModuleLoad()
    {
        HorizontalSplitPanel split = new HorizontalSplitPanel();
        //split.setSize("250px", "500px");
        split.setSplitPosition("30%");

        DecoratorPanel dp = new DecoratorPanel();
        dp.setWidget(split);

        RootPanel.get().add(dp);
    }

}
```

With the previous code snippet, nothing shows up.  Is there a method call I am missing?

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE Sep 17 '08 at 20:15**

I put some buttons (explicitly set their size) on each side and that still doesn't work. I'm really surprised there isn't like a FillLayout class or a setFillLayout method or setDockStyle(DockStyle.Fill) or something like that. Maybe it's not possible? But for as popular as GWT is, I would think it would be possible.

**UPDATE Sep 18 '08 at 14:38**

I have tried setting the RootPanel width and height to 100% and that still didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion though, that seemed like it maybe was going to work. Any other suggestions??

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Google has answered the main part of your question in one of their FAQs:
http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/FAQ_UI.html#How_do_I_create_an_app_that_fills_the_page_vertically_when_the_b

The primary point is that you can't set height to 100%, you must do something like this:

```
final VerticalPanel vp = new VerticalPanel();
vp.add(mainPanel);
vp.setWidth("100%");
vp.setHeight(Window.getClientHeight() + "px");
Window.addResizeHandler(new ResizeHandler() {

  public void onResize(ResizeEvent event) {
    int height = event.getHeight();
    vp.setHeight(height + "px");
  }
});
RootPanel.get().add(vp);
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but there are capabilities for this built-in to GWT now. See my answer for some links.

Answer (score 13):

Ben's answer is very good, but is also out of date.  A resize handler was necessary in GWT 1.6, but we are at 2.4 now.  You can use a [DockLayoutPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DockLayoutPanel.html) to have your content fill the page vertically.  See the [sample mail app](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Mail/Mail.html), which uses this panel.

Comment: here's the source: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/mail/src/com/google/gwt/sample/mail/client/Mail.java

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to put something on the left and/or right of the split (split.setLeftWidget(widget), split.setRightWidget(widget) OR split.add(widget), which will add first to the left, then to the right) in order for anything to show up.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the width and/or height of the rootpanel to 100% before adding your widget.

Answer (score 0):

Panels automatically resize to the smallest visible width. So you must resize every panel you add to the RootPanel to 100% including your SplitPanel. The RootPanel itself does not need resizing. So try:

```
split.setWidth("100%");
split.setHeight("100%");
```

Comment: Drejc,

Thanks for your response.  I tried setting both the SplitPanel dimensions and the RootPanel dimensions to 100%.  Still no luck.  Thanks again.

Comment: Set your CSS style so the panel borders are visible. You will then see which panel needs to be resized. This is my preferred way of troubleshooting when I'm somehow lost in panels and I don't know which one is responsible for what.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [DecoratorPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DecoratorPanel.html) says:

> If you set the width or height of the DecoratorPanel, you need to set the height and width of the middleCenter cell to 100% so that the middleCenter cell takes up all of the available space. If you do not set the width and height of the DecoratorPanel, it will wrap its contents tightly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that DecoratorPanel middleCenter cell will fill tight on your contents as default, and SplitPanel doesn't allow "100%" style size setting. 
To do what you want, set the table's style appropriately, on your CSS:

.gwt-DecoratorPanel .middleCenter {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
 }

Answer (score 0):

For me it does not work if I just set the width like

> panel.setWidth("100%");

The panel is a VerticalPanel that it just got a randomly size that I don't know where it comes from. But what @Ben Bederson commented worked very well for me after I added the line:

> panel.setWidth(Window.getClientWidth() + "px");

Just this, nothing else. Thanks