# How to make GWT StackLayoutPanel height set to 100%

Tags: gwt

I have used a simple stacklayoutPanel in my application ,but i am not able to make it height to 100% ,I can only fix its height which i dont want

Is there any way i can make it height to 100% insted of "300px" as i am doing with width

```
<ui:style>
    .important {
    font-weight: bold;
    }
</ui:style>

<g:HTMLPanel ui:field="stack">
<g:StackLayoutPanel unit="PX" width="100%" height="300px" >

<g:stack>
    <g:header size="30">IntraVUE</g:header>
    <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="intraVues"></g:HTMLPanel>
</g:stack>
```

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86901/creating-a-fluid-panel-in-gwt-to-fill-the-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use any of layout panels, you should use only layout panels throughout the hierarchy if you are setting the width and height in percentages starting from **RootLayouPanel**. Then automatically your stacklayoupanel height will be 100% provided you set the height to be 100%. For simillar issues, refer the following links

[GWT Re-sizing components on browser window resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771922/gwt-re-sizing-components-on-browser-window-resize)

[GWT: DataGrid - set height 100% not rendering properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845196/gwt-datagrid-set-height-100-not-rendering-properly)